# Como criar Carrousel com conteúdo do query post no Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Quero criar um Carrosel horizontal igual desse [site](http://www.patrimovel.com.br/).

Porém, quero puxar a *thumb*, título e posts de uma certa categoria.

Comment: Por favor, especifique melhor a sua pergunta, pois há inúmeras respostas para a mesma.

Comment: Você deve ser mais específico em sua pergunta...

Comment: Cara, dá uma melhorada na sua pergunta, pois ela não está muito clara. Eu não consegui entender o que você quer e não sou o único. Senão, logo logo o pessoal vai acabar fechando a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o carrosel você pode utilizar o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) ou o [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). E adaptar o efeito com algum plugin do jQuery de sua escolha.

E para fazer a parte do Wordpress você pode utilizar um código parecido com esse:

```
<?php
    query_posts ( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=3' );
    if (have_posts ()) : while ( have_posts () ) :
        the_post ();
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
        $url = $thumb ['0'];
?>
<!-- Carrosel aqui! -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se for o caso de realmente implementar o efeito que você deseja eu não posso te ajudar porém tenho uma informação que eu julgo importante para você.
Este um [artigo recente](http://mashable.com/2014/01/14/outdated-web-features/) que diz que este efeito que você pretende fazer possui algumas desvantagens que podem leva-lo a "sair de moda" este ano. 
Segundo o artigo o tempo configurado para as imagens passarem para o usuário em geral ou é muito curto ou muito longo, compromentendo a experencia deste com o site. 
O artigo diz ainda que um bom video de introdução pode ser uma melhor alternativa ao efeito.